# Qualitative behavior of solutions of a six-dimensional system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the triplet of harmonic oscillators: 
$$x_1''=-x_1$$ $$x_2''=-2x_2$$ $$x_3''=-\omega^2x_3$$
where $\omega$ is irrational. What can you say about the qualitative behavior of solutions of this six-dimensional system?

Comment: What can you say about it?  The solution curves can obviously be described explicitly, so you need to clarify what qualitative aspects you are interested in.

Comment: Just saying that $\omega$ is irrational isn't enough.$1$ is rational, $\omega$ is irrational and $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational too, so there is some space for subtlety.